# Parar de reproduzir o som ao sair do aplicativo

Tags: android

Estou criando um aplicativo, em **JAVA**, que reproduz músicas ao apertar em um determinado botão.
Mas ao apertar o botão novamente, a música é repetida. E eu gostaria de pará-la ao tocar no mesmo botão.

```
package dagustin.southamericamemes;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickTocar(View view){

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.morre);
        mp.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: Murilo, poderia colocar um trecho do código?

Comment: Opa claro vou pegar ele aqui.

Comment: Ops, amigo sou novo no StackOVerflow como faço para colar ele como se fosse um codigo mesmo?

Comment: Murilo, clica em editar na pergunta que você fez, ai depois cole o codigo.

Comment: Continua ficando como se fosse um texto normal

Comment: murilo para adicionar formatação deve-se colocar na sua pergunta, comentarios nao podem inserir formatações especificas

clique em editar sua resposta, e no campo com {} selecione o seu codigo e clique neste botão.  o código se indentará automaticamente
lembre-se de colocar espaços e afins, já que a indentação não coloca  paragrafos, apenas acerta aos padroes

Comment: Ok, obrigado vou tentar

Comment: Opa, William, consegui agora, mais abaixo esta o codigo.

Comment: Caso tenha duvidas de como fazer corretamente siga o tour do site
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Obrigado, ja tinha visto uma resposta nesse "forum" mas nao tinha entendido a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assim:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaPlayer mp

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClickTocar(View view) {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.reset();
        } else {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.morre);
            mp.start();

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado :)

Comment: Ela tambem vai funcionar para quando a pessoa sair do app, parar de tocar o som?

Comment: Sim. Para ao sair.

Comment: Ok, obrigado vou fazer a compilaçao de teste e testar.

Comment: Reginaldo, coloquei o codigo aqui no meu Android Studio, mas ele esta dando erro no codigo, nas partes: Mp.Prepare(); , @Override(o 2 Override) e no: Public void OnPause() {( Ele diz que era esperado um ponto e virgula depois das aspas do onPause, eu boto e nao sai o erro), sabe como me ajudar?

Comment: Eu escrevi no notepad. Por isso que as chaves não estão fechando. Alterei o código. Veja agora.

Comment: Opa, obrigado, tentei de varias formas resolver mas não tinha conseguido.

Comment: Amigo, agora só estao dando erro no: Mp.prepare()

Comment: @MuriloDagustin que erro aparece? se for algo em relação a ultima implementação poste/comente para olharmos!

Comment: De fato, essa foi a ultima linha que eu coloquei. Estava sem, mas me lembrei que após um stop, prepare deve ser chamada. Enfim, tire-a e veja se roda sem problema. 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare()

Comment: Opa Reginaldo, funcionou sim, muito obrigado!

Comment: Amigos, descobri outro problema, Se eu apertar de novo no botão ele para de reproduzir o som e não reproduz mais, tem que fechar o APP e abrir de novo, o mesmo acontece se esperar acabar o som e apertar novamente no botão ele não reproduz, tem que fechar o app e abri-lo novamente.

Comment: @MuriloDagustin alterei o código.